# how do I customise the default kendoui menu?

Tags: kendo-ui

I have implemented the default kendo menu using MVC. how do I change the colour and the look of it?
is there any helpful links? or any documentation? I know its all Css. I just need to know what the css is any help would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are some official documents.

See [this link](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/web/appearance-styling) if you are generally interested in how kendo UI can be customized.

And [here](http://demos.kendoui.com/themebuilder/web.html), you can even style on the go what you like, and export the styles ass CSS or LESS.
Alternatively you can also include the ThemeBuilder on your site! See the 3-point instructions guide on the site.

```
3. Use the ThemeBuilder as a bookmarklet on your own pages! (Drag the button to your bookmarks bar)
```

**EDIT:**

Since you are wondering how to style the elements themselves, inspect the menu through a tool like firebug.
You would then see the structure of the menu, and can style the classes individually.
For example, the menu in [this link](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/menu/index.html), contains of the following html:

```
<ul id="menu" data-role="menu" class="k-widget k-reset k-header k-menu k-menu-horizontal" tabindex="0" role="menubar">
    <!-- snip -->
    <li class="k-item k-state-default" role="menuitem">
        <span class="k-link">
            Blog
        </span>
   </li>
   <!-- snip -->
</ul>
```

You could then for example style the following:

```
.k-menu .k-item {
    min-width: 140px;
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

To change the menu in the way that only the menu-items are colored, use the following definitions:

```
.k-menu.k-header {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: none;
}
.k-menu .k-item {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: thanks for that, but where does it talk about sub menu css? or the width and height of each of the elements?

Comment: thanks for that.. worked out how to use that to get the sub menus coloured.  One more question though, at the moment the menu runs all the way to the left, even when I have two menu items.  Do you know how I can stop the menu bar running all the way across? I just want it to stop after the menu items

Comment: Place the menu in an container which has dimensions. To colorize them, use a selector like k.menu .k-item .k-popup. These are things that you actually could find out if you'd use something like Firebug...

Comment: I am using the chrome debugging tools.  I have placed a div container called 'MainNavContainer' in that I have my menu control called 'MainNav'.  The only issue I am having is menu still extends to the end of the container, which is fine, but I need the extending menu in a colour (red).. I have tried #MainNav .k.menu .k-item .k-popup .k-widget { background-color: red;} the menu items are fine.. I can color them in its the extendng bit

Comment: this is a screen shot of the issue I am trying to solve... thanks   https://anonfiles.com/file/5be9960ec139e4bbf5e7be23855d0cc1

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks for the screenshot. :). I edited my answer. See edit 2

Comment: thanks.. now I am able to make the circled area red.. now this is the next question how do I get rid of the circled area all together.. I tried making the background-color none.. didn't work.. here is my  css

Comment: #MainNavContainer {width:80%;}

#MainNav {  border: 0; background-image: none; background-color:none; }
#MainNav .k.menu .k-item .k-popup .k-widget { background-color: red;}
#MainNav .k-link {color: white; background-color: #145797;     min-width: 150px;}
#MainNav li:first-child .k-link {border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;}
#MainNav li:last-child .k-link {border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;}
#MainNav .k-icon { display: none; }

Comment: #MainNav li.k-state-hover .k-link, #MainNav .k-state-active { background-color: #478ACB; }

#MainNav li .k-group li.k-state-hover .k-link { color: #378699; background-color: #EBEBEB; border-radius: 0; }

#MainNav li .k-group li .k-link { border: 0; color: #426b83; background-color: #fff; border-radius: 0;}

Comment: managed to fix all issues bar one.  Here si the screen shot.  How can I get rid of the hovering issue I am having?https://anonfiles.com/file/5612896eb2dca15dc60b973fe950b823